# Upload File and write path to text-field in Frontend/User Edit Form

Tags: members, file-uploads, solspace-user, saef

Is there a way to upload a file in a Frontend Edit Form (Solspaces «User») and write the new file-path into a member-custom-field (text-field).

The goal is to let users add/upload more than only one Membership-Photo to their profiles.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you could do exactly what you're asking, but have you considered using one of the member module add-ons like [Profile:Edit](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/profileedit) or [Zoo Visitor](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zoo-visitor)? They both allow you to tie a channel entry to a member, so you can have whatever custom fields you like. Profile:Edit has the added benefit of being developed on top of Safecracker, so it works exactly the same as a normal Safecracker form.

Comment: Profile:Edit or Zoo Visitor aren't options right now for this Project. There are also future plans for Login/Registrations via Facebook/Twitter/Google+ etc. and this MAY cause problems with these AddOns(?). But more important: we're still hoping EllisLab will feature custom fields types for Members in a soon to come feature EE-Release (One can always dream! ;-) ) and do not want to switch back-and-forth for this crucial part… 'till this is reality, we're looking for a compromise between the given member custom field types and some custom solutions… like this file-upload-to-text-field ;-)

Comment: In that case I think you'd need to write a custom extension to grab the data from SafeCracker and stuff it into a member field. Not too difficult, but there's definitely nothing pre-built to do that.

Comment: Ah, sorry, with «SAEF» I actually mean a stand-alone-entry-form with Solspaces «User»-Edit-Form :-) (I've edited the Question)